# When I display FIDS, I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: jquery, json, rest

Is anyone familiar with flightstats.com? I'm trying to display the following query but I have no idea where to start.

https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/airport/tracks/lax/dep?appId=fd8dc559&appKey=5b91a5f8189287d465050785efb2d974&includeFlightPlan=false&maxPositions=2&maxFlights=5

My host is using classic ASP and HTML.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $.getJSON("https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/jsonp/fs/PDX?appId=fd8dc559&appKey=5b91a5f8189287d465050785efb2d974&callback=airportResult", function(result){
                        $.each(result, function(i, field){
                            $("div").append(field + " ");
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Get JSON data</button>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!